# Rewrite URL from "customer.php" to "?customer="

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a URL like this

> abc.com/my-data/customer.php?id=2

And I would like to convert that URL to

> abc.com/my-data/?customer=&id=2

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^my-data/customer\.php$ /my-data/?customer=&id=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert that URL you need this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(my-data)/customer.php\?id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^(my-data)/(\d+)/?$ $1/customer.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```